# I am getting error in my Angular code I am unable to find the solution because I am new to this field

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, web-frontend

[image: This is the code]

[image: This is the error]

[this is the GitHub code that I coded as it is watching his youtube video](https://github.com/RameshMF/Angular-10-Spring-Boot-CRUD-Full-Stack-App/blob/master/angular-frontend/src/app/update-employee/update-employee.component.ts)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post code as links to images, but as text with proper code tags.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear so I can answer:

```js
constructor(
  employeeService: EmployeeService
) { ... }
```

When you write this, the scope of your variable is only the constructor itself.

To declare it as a class-scoped variable, you have to set it :

```js
private employeeService: EmployeeService;

constructor(
  employeeService: EmployeeService
) {
  this.employeeService = employeeService;
}
```

You can also use typescript's shortcut feature like such :

```js
constructor(
  private employeeService: EmployeeService
) { ... }
```

Which will achieve the same result.